# Has anyone ever used the "scroll arrows" in the horizontal scroll bar to scroll the positions?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, user-controls

I wish to use the scroll arrows present at both the ends of the scroll bar, to scroll the positions of the bar. As it is known that the scroll bars don't have the notifications as other controls have, so I am facing a problem.

My code for the scroll bar is as follows-

```
void CScrollBarExDlg::OnHScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar)
{
    if(nSBCode==SB_THUMBPOSITION)
    {
        if(pScrollBar==&m_Scroll)
        {

            m_Edit=nPos;
            m_Scroll.SetScrollPos(nPos);
        }

    }
    UpdateData(FALSE);


    CDialogEx::OnHScroll(nSBCode, nPos, pScrollBar);
}
```

Comment: `so I am facing a problem` You seem to have forgotten to explain *what* problem you are facing.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik a problem in handling the scroll arrows.. can u answer me now ??

Comment: What problem do you have in handling the scroll arrows?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I have no idea how to handle them or how to activate them..

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `OnHScroll`, and in particular the description of `nSBCode` parameter? What other values, besides `SB_THUMBPOSITION`, may it have?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik are you talking about the MSDN documentation ?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about MSDN documentation.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yup, but there is no info on scroll arrows over there..

Comment: If you place a breakpoint inside the function, click on the arrow, then inspect `nSBCode` in the debugger once the breakpoint is hit, what value does the variable have?

Comment: Now, if you right-click on `SB_THUMBPOSITION` and choose `Go to definition`, how is it defined? Other constants are defined nearby - what values do they have?

Comment: `#define SB_LINEUP           0
#define SB_LINELEFT         0
#define SB_LINEDOWN         1
#define SB_LINERIGHT        1
#define SB_PAGEUP           2
#define SB_PAGELEFT         2
#define SB_PAGEDOWN         3
#define SB_PAGERIGHT        3
#define SB_THUMBPOSITION    4
#define SB_THUMBTRACK       5
#define SB_TOP              6
#define SB_LEFT             6
#define SB_BOTTOM           7
#define SB_RIGHT            7
#define SB_ENDSCROLL        8`

Comment: So, which of the constants described in the documentation for `OnHScroll` has the same value as `nSBCode` parameter you observe when clicking on the arrow?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `SB_THUMBTRACK`

Comment: Do you sincerely believe that `3 == 5`?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik actually i re-build it and then wrote that comment, because previously i hadn't clicked the scroll arrow.. now i have finally rebuild it and clicked the scroll arrow, now i get the`nSBCode` as 1

Comment: So, which of the constants described in the documentation for `OnHScroll` has the same value as `nSBCode` parameter you observe when clicking on the arrow - that is, `1`?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `SB_LINEDOWN` and `SB_LINERIGHT`

Comment: Well, only one of them is mentioned in the documentation for `OnHScroll` (the other is mentioned for `OnVScroll`; it's not by accident that they have the same numeric value). Anyway, now you have enough information to adjust your code so it checks for the click on the scroll arrow.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks man :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify the [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e14hhbe6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) slightly to work with a scroller control:

```
//add to message map
ON_WM_HSCROLL()

//initialize in OnInitDialog
SCROLLINFO info = { sizeof(SCROLLINFO) };
info.nMin = 0;
info.nMax = 100;
info.nPage = 1; 
info.fMask = SIF_ALL;
m_Scroll.SetScrollInfo(&info, TRUE);
```

If `info.nPage` is greater than 1, it may throw off the range. Add this line to fix it:

```
info.nMax += info.nPage - 1;
```

Add overload:

```
void CMyDialog::OnHScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar)
{
    CDialog::OnVScroll(nSBCode, nPos, pScrollBar);
    if (pScrollBar == &m_Scroll)
    {
        //get scrollbar information
        SCROLLINFO info;
        m_Scroll.GetScrollInfo(&info, SIF_ALL);
        int pos = info.nPos;

        //calculate the new position of scroll box 
        switch (nSBCode)
        {
        case SB_LEFT: pos = info.nMin; break;
        case SB_RIGHT: pos = info.nMax; break;
        case SB_LINELEFT: pos--; break;
        case SB_LINERIGHT: pos++;  break;
        case SB_PAGELEFT: pos -= info.nPage; break;
        case SB_PAGERIGHT: pos += info.nPage; break;
        case SB_THUMBPOSITION: pos = nPos; break;
        case SB_THUMBTRACK: pos = nPos; break;
        }

        //make sure the new position is within range
        if (pos < info.nMin) pos = info.nMin;

        //adjust the max value, incase we had changed it earlier in OnInitDialog
        int max = info.nMax - info.nPage + 1;
        if (pos > max) pos = max;

        //set the new position
        m_Scroll.SetScrollPos(pos);
    }
}
```

Comment: `nPage` should be set to 1. See the edit if you need to set `nPage` to another value. Although it shouldn't be necessary. You may also want to look at Slider control.